# Styling Checkbox in Laravel Form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, bootstrap-material-design, laravel-form

I am using Laravel Forms package to generate the form elements. I am using Bootstrap Material design library to get the elements shiny.

Library: https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/#checkbox

For Checkboxes, I am not able to get the style as required. It displays a normal checkbox without any material design style.

Below is my code in Laravel view.

```
{!! Form::checkbox('remember', 1, null, ['id'=>'remember', 'class' => 'checkbox']) !!}
{!! Form::label('remember', 'Remember me') !!}
```

Instead of the above code, if I use the direct HTML code, it works. Below is the code that works as expected.

```
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input name="remember" type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
```

How can I generate the above code using Laravel Forms?

Comment: What does the code render?

Comment: As mentioned in question, it renders a standard chckbox without any material design style.

Comment: Ok, I ran your code and I receive the checkbox with the css applied to it. This is weird.

Comment: You mean the Form::checkbox() code or the bottom HTML code with Material Design library?

Comment: The `Form::checkbox()` code returns `<input id="remember" class="checkbox" name="remember" type="checkbox" value="1">`.

Comment: Does it have the Bootstrap Material design style applied as shown in https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/#checkbox ?

Comment: No, you will need a form macro to this. http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#custom-macros

Comment: Sorry, all other elements gets the style but not woth checkbox.

Answer (score -1):

The styling of the checkbox is on `input[type="checkbox"]` and not in the checkbox class.

create a css as

```
.checkbox {}
```

to style the checkbox.

Comment: Styling is taken care of the Material design library. So I guess we don't have to play with the CSS.

Comment: I suggested a workaround i.e. to copy contents of input[type="checkbox"] into .checkbox

Comment: I got it now. But I am looking for a Laravel solution. Thanks a lot.